# What does substituting a population total for an estimate mean for the standard error?

Tags: sample-size, standard-error, proportion, estimators

I have to calculate the minimum sample size for a proportion estimate required in order to meet a criterium on the standard error of this kind:

$$
\text{SE}_P = \sqrt{\frac{P(1-P)}{n}}  \sqrt\frac{N-n}{N-1} \lt \text{SE}_\text{req}
$$

Where $\text{SE}_\text{req}$ is a constant (calculated by a formula).

However, the population size $N$ is itself an estimate.

I am trying to find out whether I can just substitute this estimate into the formula for $\text{SE}_P$ or if the fact that $N$ is an estimate changes the standard error? I have no luck googling it.

Comment: The $\sqrt{(N-n)/(N-1)}$ term is also known as the _finite population correction_ (fpc) factor. I haven't seen an example of how the fpc changes if $N$ is unknown but that may be a good path forward to answer this question. There are cases where the fpc can be ignored but that doesn't really answer your question.

Comment: Can you give more info on how $N$ was estimated? Was it assumed to be _normally_ distributed?

Answer (score 0):

I've been watching this question hoping someone would step in and drop some statistical theory for us but until then I can point to a possible applied solution to your problem.

I mentioned in my comment that the $\sqrt{(N-n)(N-1)}$ term is also known as the finite population correction (fpc) factor. The name is pretty self explanatory: it's used to *correct* the estimate when the *population* is *finite*. I found [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/80195/119085) gave a ton of intuition for the fpc as this being a case where you are sampling from a *Hypergeometric* distribution.

If we assumed the population was infinite then the classical way to estimate the sample size no longer depends on the fpc and is:

$$
n = \frac{p(1-p)}{\text{SE}^2}
$$

For this case, let's say we want to estimate the true proportion of $p$ to a standard error of no worse than $0.05$ (5 percentage points) and to be conservative we choose that $p=0.5$. Then we would have the following (code in `Julia`):

```
se = 0.05
p = 0.5
n = (p / se)^2
n
```

```
## 100
```

Now we can see the effect that a *finite* population has on this estimated sample size as well. Given the formula from your question we could solve this for $n$ and we'd have the following:

$$
n = \frac{N}{\frac{\text{SE}^2(N-1)}{p(1-p)} + 1}
$$

If we reuse our chosen $\text{SE}$ and $p$ and assume we know the total population and it is $N = 100$, then the estimated sample size would be:

```
N = 100
N / ((N - 1) * (se)^2 / (p * (1-p)) + 1)
```

```
## 50.25
```

This definitely jives with our intuition that we shouldn't need as many samples if the population is small.

Getting back to your question, there are a couple ways I could think of propagating the uncertainty of the estimated $\hat N$:

1. If we are dealing with a linear function then we could use *linear uncertainty propagation*. If you're familiar with the `Julia` programming language, there is a package called [Measurements.jl](https://github.com/JuliaPhysics/Measurements.jl) that makes this very easy.
2. If we are dealing with a non-linear function then we could use *Monte-Carlo sampling* instead. In `Julia` the [MonteCarloMeasurements.jl](https://github.com/baggepinnen/MonteCarloMeasurements.jl) package has this implemented.

We can verify if the function we're working with is linear or non-linear with respect to $N$ by plotting the function:

```
using CairoMakie

xs = 0:0.01:600
ys = @. xs / ((xs - 1) * (se)^2 / (p * (1-p)) + 1)
lines(xs, ys; axis=(; xlabel=L"N", ylabel=L"n"))
```

[image: nonlinear]

The above plot shows us this function is non-linear with respect to $N$ and is approaching $100$ as $N \to \infty$. Since it's non-linear we should make use of simulations to better understand $n$ given $\hat N$:

```
using MonteCarloMeasurements

N_est = 100 ± 25 # Construct Gaussian uncertain parameter
n_est = N_est / ((N_est - 1) * (se)^2 / (p * (1-p)) + 1)
n_est
```

```
## Particles{Float64, 2000}
##  49.4265 ± 6.69
```

The result from above could be a bit misleading since it gives you back a $\pm$ but this does not mean the result is symmetric so it's good to plot the raw samples to have a better idea of what's going on:

```
samp_quant = pquantile(n_est, [0.025, 0.5, 0.975])
hist(Array(n_est), bins = 50, axis = (;xlabel=L"n", title = "Samples of estimated sample size after population uncertainty propagation"))
vlines!(samp_quant, color = :black, linestyle = :dash)
current_figure()
```

[image: samples]

So via simulation we have a distribution for $n$ and we can now see this distribution is a bit skewed.

If we wouldn't have taken into account the uncertainty of $\hat N$ then we would have chosen $n \approx 50$ (note that's our median as well) but given that we can do uncertainty propagation we may want to choose a more conservative choice of $n \approx 60$.

Another thing this answer doesn't address is *power* but your question didn't mention it so I'll just leave this reference to Chapter 16 (Design and Sample Size Decisions) in *Regression and Other Stories* by Andrew Gelman, Jennifer Hill, Aki Vehtari. The pdf is free for personal use and can be found at the following [link](https://avehtari.github.io/ROS-Examples/index.html).